# insert values from an array into mySQL Query

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp

```
$test = array(10,20);
$rez = $this->Schimb->query("SELECT `pret`,`valuta` FROM schimb ORDER BY pret*{$test['valuta']} DESC");
```

I can't insert values from an array into MySQL Query...where is the problem?

Comment: the problem probably has something to do with how `Schimb` dude parses your SQL string

Comment: can you explain what is this pret*{$test['valuta']}

Comment: pret*{$test['valuta']} valuta is in my DB and is 0 and 1....and i whant valuta to be the key of my array test...sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are trying to use your regular array as an *associative array* (indexed by a string key in this case). Try to use the *array position* as key instead.

```
$test[0], $test[1] etc...
```

Example:

```
$rez = $this->Schimb->query("SELECT `pret`,`valuta` FROM schimb ORDER BY pret{$test[0]} DESC");
```

But could it be the case that you should only `ORDER BY` the column pret instead?

Comment: in this case everything works...but i need array keys to be tooked from BD